# From OOP to ReactJs: Why I should remove the local State from a Component and move it to their Parent?

Tags: reactjs

I would say that I have good experience with a lot of OOP languages. Most with Java. I've made full stack development with Spring boot and now i'm trying to learn React.

My point with all this is that maybe I'm to used to OOP languages so there are some "design philosophies" that I cannot understand.

I've started with this tutorial video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ke90Tje7VS0

It's pretty great and clear but I have an issue in one part in particular:

1:47:55 **Removing the Local State**

To summarize the video, he makes an component called Counters that contains N componentes called Counter.  This component Counter is just one number and a button that every time is pressed the value should increments by 1.

Originally, this value was stored as an state in the Counter component. This makes sense thinking in a OOP way. But then, in that chapter from the video he suggested to remove that state and mantain that value in the parent component, Counters.

And every time the button "INCREASE" is pressed, what is doing is calling Increment in the parent component. The value is stored in Counters. Not Counter.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Now, my question:** Why not keep the VALUE state in the Counter component, and everytime is increased, inform the parent component that this happened?

How is this design philophy called? Any tutorial/book/video that explain this better for the people that comes from a OOP background?

Sorry is this is a dumb question. Thanks!

Comment: OOP principles still apply. Here some good reads https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html and https://dev.to/bouhm/thinking-in-react-component-composition-fp5

Answer (score 4):

The goal of this is to have a "single source of truth". In other words, if this piece of state is only kept in one place, then it's impossible to have a conflict between different versions, because different versions don't exist. And this in turn means you don't have to devote any effort or code to trying to keep states in sync with eachother.

---

Now in principle you might think of having the child component be that single source of truth. But the way react is designed, props always flow from the top of the component tree to the bottom. A parent component passes props to a child component, not vice versa, so react makes it very convenient for the state to exist in the parent component and then be passed to a child.

As you mentioned, the child could notify the parent of changes, which would be done through a function prop. But in order for the parent to rerender and use this new data, it will then need to set state on itself (`setState` causes `render`). And now the state is being kept in two places, which is the thing we were trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

The design philosophy is known as smart vs dumb components and it becomes more useful when dealing with larger state management libraries like `Redux`. The goal is to separate your logical components, those that deal with manipulating the state, interacting with other libraries like `Redux` etc. From view components. That way your view gets to be a pure function, reacting only to the parameters passed explicitly to it. This makes them extremely easy to test. And you only have to test that your smart components are passing the correct values to the view only components. Decoupling in this way makes testing smoother and prevents a variety of bugs that could otherwise be difficult to track down.